# Node not working in zsh

Tags: bash, npm, homebrew, zsh

Today was the 1st day of my coding bootcamp and they have us a script that installs all the development cli tools we are gonna use in class. I was using zsh before installing this script and node was working just fine. After running this script none of my previous node, homebrew or any other packages that this script installed works in zsh but they all work in bash. Is there anyway to fix this ?

Comment: This is far too vague to answer with anything other than "yes".

Comment: I'm not really sure how better to word this as I don't have any errors to provide. I know they are installed on my machine because when I type node in bash it runs.

Comment: Does bash install node in a separate folder than zsh would?

Comment: No idea; we don't know what script you were given to install the tools.

Comment: This is the script https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GA-WDI/installfest/master/builds/mac

Comment: that script deleted your previous `node` installation and installed a new copy of `node`. it also modified your `~/.bash_profile` to make the location of the new installation known to `bash`, but not so for poor `zsh`. open `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.zshrc` side-by-side, and add any lines from `.bash_profile` related to `PATH` or `node` or `nvm` to the end of `.zshrc`.

Comment: Thanks that worked :D

Answer (score 3):

On windows bash WSL I had to copy this from `.bashrc` to `zshrc` based on suggestion by AGDM, but not everything (like with source) or you get a ton of errors. I can finally run npm -v and the usual stuff like npm run start my react app from zsh in vscode.

```
# npm was not working
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Answer (score 1):

For node commands via terminal, like `npm i <some-cool-npm-jam> --save-dev`.

I copied the contents of `.bashrc` to `.zshrc` to run the node commands in zsh mode.

Worked flawlessly.